# How do I get out of the "Welcome Back" screen?

Tags: steam-monster-game

I started playing the game yesterday, but when I came back today, I was greeted with a "Welcome Back" screen that invited me to buy stuff with my badge points. The game is still going on behind it, but there is no close button on the dialog. How would I get out of it and continue playing the game?

Comment: Do I have to spend all of my badge points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to dismiss this dialog, you have to spend all of your badge points.

(I suggest stocking up on some Treasure consumables, as they are cheap and will help you get ahead in the early game.)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot spend your badge points or are stuck on that screen just close and restart Steam.

Mine was stuck on the "Welcome Back!" screen as well, was not registering any of my clicks to spend the points, therefore I was stuck there. Restarting Steam worked for me!

Happy gaming!